# iOS ionic leaflet - Click on map not registered

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, leaflet

I'm using a leaflet map via mapbox.js in a hybrid platform developed with the Ionic framework. Everything works well so far except for clicking on a Marker in iOS. On all the other platforms (Chrome, Webapp on Android, Androidapp) one tap on the marker is enough to fire the click event. On iOS I always need to tap the marker two times before it fires the event. The problem is the same whether I use the app as Webapp in Safari or as a standalone app via Cordova.
Any ideas what I can do to get the same behaviour on iOS as on other platforms?

Edit:
I discovered that it's probably only the first tap after the map get's rerendered that is lost. After the first interaction (tap, drag, zoom) with the map one tap is enough to trigger the event

Comment: What version are you using? 0.7.3 or master?

Comment: I'm using mapbox.js which uses 0.7.3 as far as I know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic/angular leaflet directive - zoom in/out buttons do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675208/ionic-angular-leaflet-directive-zoom-in-out-buttons-do-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

There are only two settings related to tapping. The `tap` option of `L.Map` which enables some mobile "hacks", you could give that a try:

> Enables mobile hacks for supporting instant taps (fixing 200ms click delay on iOS/Android) and touch holds (fired as contextmenu events).

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-tap

The other is related to tolerance which i don't think is your problem. But there seems to be an issue which has not yet been able to be tested because the user who reported it doesn't respond anymore. If the above won't work maybe you can help out Mourner and do some testing, see:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3184

Comment: I already tried using the tap option, which didn't help. I'm going to have a look at the Github issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the attribute `data-tap-disabled="true"` to the element containing the map's div. That fixed the same problem that I had using Leaflet in an Ionic-based app on Android